# need to produce a function that detects the zeros in a array

Tags: c++

I have this code but is not working , it keep giving me the following errors :

```
[Error] cannot convert 'float' to 'float*' for argument '1' to 'void zeroCrossing(float*, float*, int)'

[Error] cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' for argument '1' to 'bool getSign(float)'

[Error] cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' for argument '1' to 'bool getSign(float)'

[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'float*' [-fpermissive]
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void zeroCrossing(float *data, float *zerCross, int nx);
bool getSign(float data);
float array[9] = {1,2,3,0,-1,-2,-3,0,1};
float *p = array;
float f1[9];
float *p2 = f1;
int bx= 2 ;

int main() {
    zeroCrossing(*p,*p2,bx);
    return 0 ;
}

/* zero crossing function */
/* data = input array */
/* zerCross = output zero crossing array */
void zeroCrossing(float *data[], float *zerCross[], int nx)
{
    int i;
    bool sign1, sign2;

    memset(zerCross, 0, nx*sizeof(float));//copies the 0  to the first characters of the string 
                                            //pointed to, by argument 

    for(i=0; i<nx-1; i++)     /* loop over data  */
    {
        sign1 = getSign(data[i]);
        sign2 = getSign(data[i+1]);
        if(sign1!=sign2)  /* set zero crossing location */
            zerCross[i+1] = 1;
    }
}
/* get sign of number */
bool getSign(float data)
{
    if(data>0)      /* positif data */
        return (1);
    else            /* negatif data */
        return (0);
}
```

Comment: Just curious, what was your interpretation of the compiler errors?

Comment: Once you fix the compiler errors, you will get *linker* errors. There's ni definition (implementation) of the function `void zeroCrossing(float *data, float *zerCross, int nx);`

Comment: The `zeroCrossing` has two different definitions. Use the first one. The `float *name[]` means pointer to array and is equivalent with `float **name`.

Comment: `zeroCrossing(*p,*p2,bx)`: You are not passing the pointers to the function, but only the first values of the arrays - as raw `float`!

Comment: A note for future questions: Your problem is entirely unrelated to "a function that detects the zeroes in an array". That is the *assignment* you are looking at; your *problem* at this point is a faulty function declaration. This problem could be reproduced with nothing more than a `void foo( float * data[] )` and an `int main()` calling that function. The question title should probably be along the lines of "why do I get conversion errors here". This is a valuable debugging technique, reducing the problem by eliminating unnecessary code until you are looking at *only* the problem.

Comment: (ctd.) At which point one of two things happens: 1) The problem becomes obvious to you, because you are no longer distracted by surrounding code / the "bigger problem", or 2) you end up with a [mcve] that will get you a very quick and to-the-point answer here.

Comment: With your `getSign` approach, you might get false positives with sequences such as `1.0, 0.0, 1.0`; changing to `>= 0` won't help, as you get false positives with `-1.0, 0.0, -1.0` then (if just touching zero is to be counted as crossing, too, you get false negatives instead of false positives).

Comment: By the way, the same way you assign `array` to `p`, you can assign it directly to the function parameters, so you can just have `zeroCrossing(array, f1, [...]`. You might want to avoid magic numbers (you noticed that 9 and 2 do not match?) by using array size as parameter: `[...], sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array));`

Answer (score 0):

When you do coding, you should compile the code after some lines of codes, unless you are pro.

There are two things I could say about your codes

1. Function declaration: `void zeroCrossing(float *data, float *zerCross, int nx);` and `void zeroCrossing(float *data[], float *zerCross[], int nx)` are not the same.
2. Variable name: Should avoid names like `array` because they are used in the standard lib.

This is my fix to make your code compilable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


void zeroCrossing(float *data, float *zerCross, int nx);
bool getSign(float data);

float array_[9] = {1,2,3,0,-1,-2,-3,0,1};
float* p = array_;
float f1[9];
float *p2 = f1;
int bx= 2 ;

/* get sign of number */
bool getSign(float data)
{
    if(data>0)      /* positif data */
        return (1);
    else            /* negatif data */
        return (0);
}


/* zero crossing function */
/* data = input array */
/* zerCross = output zero crossing array */
void zeroCrossing(float *data, float *zerCross, int nx)
{
    int i;
    bool sign1, sign2;

    memset(zerCross, 0, nx*sizeof(float));//copies the 0  to the first characters of the string
    //pointed to, by argument

    for(i=0; i<nx-1; i++)     /* loop over data  */
    {
        sign1 = getSign(data[i]);
        sign2 = getSign(data[i+1]);
        if(sign1!=sign2)  /* set zero crossing location */
            zerCross[i+1] = 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    zeroCrossing(p,p2,bx);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - you should minimize the number of global variables, in your case it is 0.
2 - `*p` points to a value stored in an address `p`, so in `main` function when you are calling `zeroCrossing` you need to pass an address, not value.

To be honest, I don't understand what you are trying to do but at least this code don't throw errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void zeroCrossing(float *data, float *zerCross, int nx);
bool getSign(float data);

int main()
{
    float array[9] = {1,2,3,0,-1,-2,-3,0,1};
    float *p = array;
    float f1[9];
    float *p2 = f1;
    int bx = 2 ;

    zeroCrossing(p, p2, bx);
    return 0 ;
}

/* zero crossing function */
/* data = input array */
/* zerCross = output zero crossing array */
void zeroCrossing(float *data, float *zerCross, int nx)
{
    int i;
    bool sign1, sign2;

    memset(zerCross, 0, nx*sizeof(float));//copies the 0  to the first characters of the string 
                                            //pointed to, by argument 
    for(i=0; i<nx-1; i++) { /* loop over data  */
        sign1 = getSign(data[i]);
        sign2 = getSign(data[i+1]);
        if(sign1!=sign2)  /* set zero crossing location */
            zerCross[i+1] = 1;
    }
}

/* get sign of number */
bool getSign(float data)
{
    if(data>0)      /* positif data */
        return (1);
    else            /* negatif data */
        return (0);
}
```

Comment: Just trying to find the zeros of an array. The array on top are just to test the code, if there is a better way to detect the zeros of an array or vector I would appreciated the help. thanks